# Saving Custom NSArray Data to iPhone

Tags: objective-c, iphone, arrays, nsuserdefaults, nsdata

I have been trying to save locally *(through NSUserDefaults)* a `NSMutableArray` of PFGeoPoints that a user creates. After much reading and research, I now know that simply saving an array with custom data is quite frankly impossible. I have tried the following in several different ways:

```
   NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
   NSMutableArray *testArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   NSArray *checkArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];

   testArray = locationList;
   PFGeoPoint *test = [locationList objectAtIndex:0];
   NSString *latString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",test.latitude];
   [testArray insertObject:latString atIndex:0];

   checkArray = testArray;

   [defaults setValue:checkArray forKey:@"Locations"];
   [defaults synchronize];
```

where locationList is a `NSMutableArray` that has been created and set to PFGeoPoints from Parse.

I had also tried converting the `NSMutableArray` to `NSData` via

```
    NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:array];
```

, but this still did not work. Each time I kept receiving the error telling me the following:

```
Property list invalid for format: 200 
(property lists cannot contain objects of type 'CFType')
```

The `NSMutableArray` that I am saving is a list that contains multiple `PFGeoPoint`s. All I am trying to do is save this array to the device, so that the user does not have to recreate *(render)* the entire list each time the user loads the application *(I am using cloud data...not trying to spend too much for data)*.

If someone could help me out with either a suggestion/solution on how to save this data as an array (rather than breaking up each line into integers for lat and long), OR if someone can suggest a helpful alternative to `NSUserDefaults` *(like perhaps Core Data or some other local storage)* I would be most appreciative. Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just save your array as an XML file in a sandbox folder assigned to your application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply you need to implement `NSCoding protocol`

**Write array:**

Obj-C

```
-(void)writeArrayWithCustomObjToUserDefaults:(NSString *)keyName withArray:(NSMutableArray *)myArray {

       NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
       NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:myArray];
       [defaults setObject:data forKey:keyName];
       [defaults synchronize]; 

}
```

Swift 2.3

```
func writeArrayWithCustomObjToUserDefaults(keyName: String, withArray myArray: [AnyObject]) {
    var defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    var data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(myArray)
    defaults.setObject(data, forKey: keyName)
    defaults.synchronize()
}
```

Swift 3.1

```
func writeArrayWithCustomObj(toUserDefaults keyName: String, withArray myArray: [Any]) {
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: myArray)
    defaults.set(data, forKey: keyName)
    defaults.synchronize()
}
```

**Read Array:**

Obj-C

```
-(NSArray *)readArrayWithCustomObjFromUserDefaults:(NSString*)keyName {

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData *data = [defaults objectForKey:keyName];
    NSArray *myArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
    [defaults synchronize];
    return myArray;  
}
```

Swift 2.3

```
func readArrayWithCustomObjFromUserDefaults(keyName: String) -> [AnyObject] {
    var defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    var data = defaults.objectForKey(keyName)!
    var myArray = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data)!
    defaults.synchronize()
    return myArray
}
```

Swift 3.1

```
func readArrayWithCustomObj(fromUserDefaults keyName: String) -> [Any] {
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let data: Data? = defaults.object(forKey: keyName)
    let myArray: [Any]? = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data!)
    defaults.synchronize()
    return myArray!
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To save custom objects into user defaults, it need to conform to `NSCoding` protocol (objects needs to code/decode).

Your custom Objects need to implement the `NSCoding` protocol.

Once you followed NSCoding rules; archive & save data like this:

```
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:yourArray];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:data forKey:@"Key"];
```

Unarchive like this:

```
NSArray *array= [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Key"];
```